# How to define the size of a letter relatively to the parenthesis that follows?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I often need to write a function whose arguments are bigger than the function name itself.
Is it possible to define the font size of f relatively to what follows in the parenthesis( i.e not using Huge, Big, etc...) ?

`f\left(\frac{\xi}{2}, \int_0^T g(s) ds\right)`

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You probably could. But more importantly, you *shouldn’t*.

Comment: Have you seen this in any publication before?